# Trouble mapping directories

Tags: reactjs, directory-structure

I have a problem with my folder mapping in a react project. Below the files and project structure. Anyone could tell me why its not working?

My react is in version "react": "^18.2.0”. Folder “src” is in the root of the project, and inside it I have the folders “components”, “assets”, “app”, “helpers”, “services” and “themes”.

jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@assets/*": [
        "./src/assets/*"
      ],
      "@components/*": [
        "./src/components/*"
      ],
      "@app/*": [
        "./src/app/*"
      ],
      "@helpers/*": [
        "./src/helpers/*"
      ],
      "@services/*": [
        "./src/services/*"
      ],
      "@themes/*": [
        "./src/themes/*"
      ],
      "@features/*": [
        "./src/app/features/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    plugins: [
      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          root: ["."],
          alias: {
            "@assets": "src/assets",
            "@components": "src/components",
            "@app": "src/app",
            "@helpers": "src/helpers",
            "@services": "src/services",
            "@themes": "src/themes",
            "@features": "src/app/features",
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

I have installed the dependencies "@babel/core": "^7.22.1" and "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0". Already restarted the server several times.

Answer (score 0):

To fully understand your issue it would be helpful to see what kind of error messages you're getting from your console. Based on what I see here it could be that you may not have all of your packages installed, or may have your App.js file in the wrong folder. Or you could have an error in your App.js file. Once again, without seeing the error you are getting it's hard to give a direct answer

Comment: ```"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "html-react-parser": "^3.0.16",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-slider": "^2.0.4",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.10",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },```

Comment: What about your console, when you run a "yarn start" or "npm start" what happens?

Comment: It gives an error sasying it can't find the path. Do you think it might have something to do with the fact that the project was created using create-react-app?

Comment: Are you running your yarn or npm start from the root folder of the project?